# How to fill data in ListView using C#

Tags: c#, listview, row

I'm new in C#.
I want my data to fill the first column first, and then the data will fill to the next column after filling the first column with user define row. The data will fill the next column when it reaches the row limit. The Rows and Columns are dynamic depends on user input. Thanks
Screenshot in the links

Input:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

```
string[] separators = { ",", " " };
int[] row = new int[Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)];
string value = textBox2.Text ;
string[] words = value.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

ArrayList val = new ArrayList();
val.Add(value);

foreach (var word in words)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(word);
    listView1.View = View.List;

}
```

Comment: Search the source before asking https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok sir thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to get rows filled based on user input for row count.

```
string[] separators = { ",", " " };
int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32("2");
string value = "2 5 6 7 8 9 0 2 1 3 4 5 6";
string[] words = value.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] rows = new string[rowCount];

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    int mod = i % rowCount;
    rows[mod] += words[i] + " ";
}

foreach (string item in rows)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}

listView1.View = View.List;
```